# MYSQL show sum and state by group

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL how to I run a query which will return the state and the total sum and group the results.

I have table like so...

```
 ==========================================
 id | state       | fieldKey
 ==========================================
 1  | Florida     | property_state
 2  | Idaho       | property_state
 3  | Florida     | property_state
 4  | Ohio        | property_state
 5  | Oregon      | property_state
 6  | California  | property_state
 7  | California  | property_state
 8  | California  | property_state
```

Here is my query which doesn't work:

```
 select sum(id), state from ProjectFieldValue where fieldKey = 'property_state' group by fieldKey
```

Here is what I want to output:

```
 2, Florida
 1, Idaho
 1, Ohio
 1, Oregon
 3, California
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use the group by state

Comment: For your expected output use count.  select count(id) as total_number, state from ProjectFieldValue where fieldKey = 'property_state' group by state

Answer (score 0):

You don´t want to sum. You simply want to COUNT, (updated)

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as Number, state 
FROM ProjectFieldValue 
WHERE fieldKey = 'property_state' 
GROUP BY state
```

Comment: hm, this just returns one result

Comment: My bad, @LargeTuna, I wrongly reused your initial statement. Try it now please.